# How to build all sequential of a table field value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to build all sequential of a table field value in SQL Server
i have a table similar this

```
a
b
b
c
d 
f
```

i need a function for this table with similar output

```
a
ab
abb
abbc
abbcd
abbdcf
```

Assuming i have a ID that orders those items.

Comment: Remember. SQL Database is there to STORE data not to FORMAT data.

Comment: @hims056 its a real question my table have more than  1 milion record like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a (gapless, increasing) ID that orders those items:

```
with tree (id, all_items) as (
  select id, cast(data as varchar(max)) as all_items
  from foo 
  where id = 1

  union all

  select c.id, p.all_items + c.data
  from foo c
    join tree p on p.id = c.id - 1
)
select all_items
from tree
```

SQLFiddle example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8840c/1

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Temp Table
(
    Id Int Identity(1,1),
    Data Varchar(1)
)
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('a')
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('b')
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('b')
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('c')
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('d')
Insert Into @Temp(Data) Values ('f')

Declare @i Int = 1, @j Int = 1,@Str Varchar(max) = '',@AllStr Varchar(max) = ''
While(@i <= (Select MAX(Id) From @Temp))
Begin
    While(@j <= @i)
    Begin
        Set @Str += (Select Data From @Temp Where Id = @j)
        Set @j += 1
    End
    Print @str 
    Set @j = 1
    Set @i += 1
    Set @Str = ''
End
```